# Arithmetic in Java: Whats wrong with my equation?

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to learn Java and came up with this challenge - Arithmetic

My code is as follows:

```
public class Arithmetic {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double mealCost = scan.nextDouble(); // original meal price
    int tipPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tip percentage
    int taxPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tax percentage
    scan.close();

    // Write your calculation code here.
    double tip = mealCost * (tipPercent / 100);
    double tax = mealCost * (taxPercent/100);
    double totalGeneralCost = mealCost + tip + tax;


    // cast the result of the rounding operation to an int and save it as totalCost 
    int totalCost = (int) Math.round(totalGeneralCost);

    // Print your result
    System.out.println(tax);
}
```

}

Granted that there was an input, how come my *tip* variable returns 0? Same goes for the *tax* variable?

Comment: Change `tipPercent` and `taxPercent` to double. (or change 100 to 100.0)

Comment: `(tipPercent / 100.0); `

Comment: don't use int if you want calculate prices

Comment: double tip = mealCost * ((double)tipPercent / 100);
    double tax = mealCost * ((double)taxPercent/100);

Comment: ((double)tipPercent / 100); use like this

Comment: since multiplication and division have the same precedence it would be sufficient to leave out the braces: `double tip = mealCost * tipPercent / 100;`